# Java socket programming: server thread will not receive request from client (connection times out)

Tags: java, sockets

I have a server class file that is compiled and executed in a remote linux machine, to which I'm connected via PuTTY

I have a client class file in my local windows 10 machine, which I compile and execute using the built-in command prompt

Server class

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ServerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket serv = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
            InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            System.out.println(ia.getHostName());
            System.out.println(ia.getHostAddress());
            Socket client = serv.accept();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            pw.println("Server says Hello, world!");
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

running `java ServerTest 5000` in the remote linux machine starts the server thread listening on port 5000 and prints the host name and IP address to the prompt. I later pass the name/address to the client to attempt to make a connection.

Now, the client class

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ClientTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String host = args[0];
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        try {
            Socket sock = new Socket(host, port);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                        new InputStreamReader(
                                            sock.getInputStream()));

            System.out.println(reader.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

running `java ClientTest [host name/address] 5000` on the local machine will attempt to connect to the server socket for a few seconds before crashing with a `Connection timed out` error. I tried using both the host name and IP address as the first argument. From what I can tell, the client does send a request and the server does begin listening, but the server never receives the request. I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I appreciate any help!

Comment: Possibly either the server's firewall or the client's or both are blocking the connection without notifying the client.  I'm inclined to guess that that would be more likely at the server.  Check your logs on both machines, and consider using a tool such as Wireshark to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Consider also monitoring whether the server ever actually succeeds in accepting a connection from the client.

Comment: What do you mean by "remote" when you say "remote linux machine"?

Comment: Be aware also that the server's idea of its own name and domain have pretty much zero relevance.  If you're identifying the server to the client by name, then be sure it resolves the name to the correct address.  Consider also sidestepping that issue altogether by just connecting by IP address in the first place.

Comment: There is no evidence here that anything was sent. Clearly you got a `ConnectException` when creating the socket, *before* sending anything. This is a network connectivity problem. Can you ping the server from the client?

Comment: @JohnBollinger, By checking logs, do you mean calling printStackTrace() on the Exception object?
As far as I'm aware, the server does not succeed in accepting a request. I say this because the client waits after sending a request and never gets an acknowledgement. In fact, it crashes with a 'Connection timed out' error. Moreover, the server executes with no errors but of course, it's stuck listening for requests, beyond which it never proceeds (the presumption here being that it never receives the request).

Comment: @HuguesMoreau, by remote, I mean opposed to my own local machine. The remote machine is running some variant of Linux and it's a physically separate machine. My machine is connected to it remotely via the internet (I'm assuming) using PuTTY.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, on the issue of the server reporting irrelevant host names, how can I fix this? How can I get the "real" host name or domain name of the machine hosting the server class?
Also, about your IP address comment - that is exactly what I did in my code. I tried both ways. Connecting to a host name and connecting to an IPv4 address, both of which were reported by the server machine while executing the server code.

Comment: @EJP, I haven't tried pinging the server but I can connect to it using PuTTY from my own laptop. If I can connect to the server this way and operate it remotely, surely there isn't a connection issue?

Comment: If you get a `ConnectException`, surely there *is* a connection issue? Until you provide an exception and stack trace it is impossible for anyone to help you further

Comment: @Manuel, by checking logs I mean checking the *system* logs, though in retrospect there's unlikely to be anything to see there.  As for the "real" host name, you seem not to be getting the point, which is that *there is no such thing*.  There is only the name(s), if any, that resolves to the desired address according to the client's name resolver.  If the server is registered in DNS then the name with which it is registered *probably* serves, and you may be able to obtain that by a reverse lookup.  Otherwise, details depend on how the client resolves hostnames.